# What's the best way to pass values among middlewares in koa.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, koa

I have a simple setup for koa.js with koa-route and koa-ejs.

```
var koa     = require('koa');
var route   = require('koa-route');
var add_ejs = require('koa-ejs');
var app     = koa();

add_ejs(app, {…});

app.use(function *(next){
    console.log( 'to do layout tweak for all requests' );
    yield next;
});

app.use(route.get('/', function *(name) {
  console.log( 'root action' );
  yield this.render('index', {name: 'Hello' });
}));
```

What's the best way to pass values between those two methods?

Answer (score 17):

`context.state` is the low-level way of sharing data between middleware. It's an object mounted on `context` that's available in all middleware.

You can use it like so:

```js
let counter = 0;

app.use((ctx, next) => {
  ctx.state.requestId = counter++;
  return next();
});

app.use((ctx, next) => {
  console.log(ctx.state.requestId);
  // => 1, 2, 3, etc
  return next();
});
```

[source](https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/b854d003638b5f5efa2228f488fab0dc31c1b2bf/test/context/state.js)

[koajs readme](https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/8ac26b1d77485bc204e5a2eb75970ac18fb7423f/docs/api/context.md#ctxstate)

Comment: Ex: `ctx.state.thingToPassToOtherMiddlware = "Something"` and in the other middlware `var thingToPassToOtherMiddlware = ctx.state.thingToPassToOtherMiddlware`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Koa [Context](http://koajs.com/#context):

```
app.use(function *(next) {
  this.foo = 'Foo';
  yield next;
});

app.use(route.get('/', function *(next) { // 'next' is probably what you want, not 'name'
  yield this.render('index', { name: this.foo });
  yield next; // pass to the next middleware
}));
```